# How to fix 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow._api' in TensorFlow Keras API with Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>()
     37   print('tf.estimator package not installed.')
     38 
---> 39 from tensorflow._api.v1 import app
     40 from tensorflow._api.v1 import bitwise
     41 from tensorflow._api.v1 import compat

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow._api'
```

This is the error I keep receiving every time I try to run my code.

I have tried reinstalling tensorflow from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl but every time I get the above error.

these are the libraries I am importing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
```

I am running Windows 10(64-bit)

Comment: have you resolved this? getting same error on mac after `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0`

Answer (score 2):

This error may be because Tensorflow might not have been installed properly in your PC.

There might be multiple reasons for that. So, there can be multiple solutions, as mentioned below.

Please let me know if your issue still persists after trying the below instructions. Thanks.

You can try

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow_estimator
pip install tensorflow tensorflow_estimator
```

Just to make sure. If the tensorflow_estimator uninstall fails (with not found) just ignore that error.

Or, you can try installing Tensorflow in `python3` prompt.

Or, In your pip install command, could you try adding the `--ignore_installed` flag

Or the error may be from the multiple Python distributions in your PC. Can you try removing all the other ones from your `PATH` file, and check if the issue is resolved.

For more information, please refer the below links.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29750

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6548